# PHP Long Polling Issues

Tags: java, php, mysql, ajax, long-polling

I have a web application which serves as the Admin Panel. It has a live chat option which connects with writers(employees) on the other end. The web application uses the following PHP code to check for online writers.

```
$q = 0;
$lasttime = isset($_POST['timestamp']) ? $_POST['timestamp'] : 0;
while ($q<5){
    sleep(3);
    $wresult = $db->query("SELECT writer_alias FROM tblwriter WHERE writer_isactive=1 AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-last_activity)<10");
    if ($wresult->num_rows){ break; }
    ++$q;
}
if ($wresult->num_rows){
    while ($row = $wresult->fetch_object()){ $writers[] = $row; } 
    $wresult->free(); 
}
echo json_encode(
    array(
        "writers" => $writers,
        "now" => time()
    )
);
```

On the application the following javascript code handles the PHP response and calls ajax again to complete the loop.

```
function UpdateCHAT(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "liveserver.php", 
        data: {update:"1",timestamp:lastime}, 
        success: 
            function(data1){
                if (data1 == null){ 
                    $(".onlinechat i").removeClass("icon-white"); 
                }else{ 
                    lastime = user_signin = Number(data1.now);
                    if (!data1.writers.length){ 
                        $(".onlinechat i").removeClass("icon-white"); 
                    }else{
                        $(".onlinechat i").removeClass("icon-white");
                        $.each(data1.writers,function(j) {
                            $("#writer_"+data1.writers[j].writer_alias).find("i").addClass("icon-white");
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }, 
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 60000,         
        complete: 
            function(){
                UpdateCHAT(); 
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Everything is working just fine except the fact that I cannot think of a way to know for offline writers since the PHP code is designed to check for the online writers, but this means if a writer is online once, he will remain online (on the application) until the PHP code dies and return empty writers.

Hope I am able to explain my point. This question is more to do with idea rather than piece of code. Any input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the PHP code always return after some time (like 2 minutes) with an empty result set (ie. no new chat lines).

JS will then do a new request immediately. If it doesn't, well, then the user is offline. Keep a `last_request` timestamp, if it's older than 2+e minutes the user is offline.

---

You could try to detect when the connection closes in PHP. Set `ignore_user_abort(true)` so you are in control of when your script dies. Then use `connection_aborted()` to check if the client closed. If he did you know he left.

A potential problem occurs if the user has two windows open: a close on one doesn't mean he left, but this may turn out to be acceptable; the user will *blip* for just a while.

---

Another solution is to use a separate ping request that just tells you "yep, I'm still here". If you haven't gotten one of those in a while the user is probably offline.

Comment: That is exactly how the application is taking care of this issue, if you go through the code, you will understand. The maximum time the server can poll is 16seconds after which it will send an empty result set. BUT IS THIS THE ONLY WAY TO DO IT? because its not real time anymore... :)

Comment: I want to extend the maximum poll period to 3/4 minutes but if I keep using the technique I am using (that you have suggested too), an offline writer will remain online on the application for that much time..

Comment: Yes. If you think about this, the way you'd like to do it is to have the client send a "I'm leaving now" request, but because of how browsers and JavaScript works, you can't. So a timeout is how you deal with session activity. I can think of two alternatives though (updating).

Comment: The 1st alternative is interesting. Will research now. Thanks.